# Save post meta foreach loop

Tags: post-meta, save-post

My brain has fallen over. How do I save this post data?
Building some key-value pairs in the form.

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $saved = $meta[$i];
        //print_r($saved);
        //echo $saved['key'];
        echo '<p>';
        echo '<label for="meta_k_'.$i.'">Key</label> ',   '<input id="meta_k_'.$i.'" type="text" name="_meta['.$i.'][key]" value="'.$saved['key'].'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<label for="meta_v_'.$i.'">Value</label> ', '<input id="meta_v_'.$i.'" type="text" name="_meta['.$i.'][value]" value="'.$saved['value'].'" />';
        echo '</p>';
    }
```

How do I save them???

```
    foreach ($_POST['_meta'] as $key => $value) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be work:

```
foreach ($_POST['_meta'] as $value) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, $value['key'], $value['value']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there. just hook your saving logic to 'save_post'.

```
add_action('save_post', 'custommeta');
function custommeta($post_id)
{
  //put your update code here
}
```